# I asked a question a while back, I think it has been deleted because I cannot find it for the life of me.

Tags: support

I was a very important question for my study, concerning probability. I don't know what to do!

Comment: Have you tried the "deleted recent questions" link at the bottom of the list of all your questions, or did you post too long ago for this to work?

Comment: thanks, did not know that! :D

Comment: This is what I hate about deleting other people's stuff. There's no notice, no way to check deleted stuff. Why doesn't S.E. allow us to access this sort of stuff?

Comment: There should at least be notification about it, to save time namely, i found it in the mean time. :)